# Should the smooth side or the rough side of a urethane bandsaw tire go against the wheel?

Tags: power-tools, tool-maintenance, band-saw

I am replacing bandsaw tires. I bought urethane replacement tires. There is a smooth side and a rough side. The manufacturers directions are clear on every step except for this point. The old tires have been on the bandsaw for AT LEAST 25 years and are made of rubber, those two differences make me leery of simply mirroring the current setup.

Does the smooth side or the rough side of the tire go against the bandsaw wheel?

If it matters the wheel is made of aluminum, the wheel itself has a crown, and the wheel has a lip on the edge to hold the tire on.

Comment: This question was crossposted from DIY.SE since the Woodworker.SE users are more likely to have been in the guts of a bandsaw. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189488/should-the-smooth-side-or-the-rough-side-of-a-urethane-bandsaw-tire-go-against-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to the manufacturer, they replied:

> Either way will work.  However I install smooth side in to the wheel.

Comment: I get the feeling it doesn't really matter. The rough side is probably just there because the same moulds for rubber tires are used, and rubber tires need the rough side for the glue to properly adhere to the rim. Since urethane tires don't need glue, it probably doesn't matter. But I'd go rough side to the rim just because that is how the tires were designed.

Comment: thanks for posting the response!